# Chrome Apps Comment Section

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

So Chrome Apps have the HTML, CSS, JS structure and with that I thought I would implement a comment section. I was able to create a comment section box with a submit button created in HTML, but it won't submit the contents of what I wrote.

This Application intends to be running online only so I figured that having a comment section is viable for something like this, but I still am a novice when it comes to making a Chrome App and I'm learning on the fly.

My question is this:

When creating a Chrome app, is it possible to make a Comment Section? If so, how do I go about submitting the contents of what the comment box holds?

Comment: Your question is poorly written. There's no code included for us to see exactly which problem you're facing, and your prose description of your code is ambiguous. I'll use my magical mind powers to read the code off your computer's screen.

Answer (score 2):

From the way you've worded your question, it sounds like you're using a <form> with a POST method. If that's the case, then which origin do you expect the submission to go to? Chrome Apps have no server component, so there isn't any meaningful origin. Moreover, even if you did a POST to a full remote-origin URL, a form submission is effectively a navigation to a new origin, and like any single-page application (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application), a Chrome App does not have a concept of navigation.

If you really do mean to submit a form to a remote origin, then you need to do it with XHR. One of many examples of XHR-based form submission is in https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/blob/master/samples/push-guestbook/guestbook-app/Guestbook.js.